# Launch a WatchKit extension from the Host App

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

How to launch a WatchKit extension from the Host Iphone App? 
I searched the documentation and all over stackoverflow but i just found the reverse(launch host app from watchkit extension).

Comment: You can't.  The user must launch the app on the watch by tapping the icon

Comment: Try using watch URL-scheme, "itms-watch://" with UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL. Even if it works I am not sure whether apple would approve of it.

Comment: @PuneetSharma it's a good idea "deep-linking" to the watch but you're right i think Apple will not approve it. But i will try just to see if it works.